# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a JavaScript error in my browser whenever I am trying to add the following two lines in the  section of my application home page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/jq/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>')</script>
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong in those two lines? and if possible how to fix it?

Thanks for your time

Comment: the JS code works fine for me

Comment: Nested `<script>` tags will break the browser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't embed the substring `</script>` anywhere within a script block.

Change your `document.write` call:

```
<script>
  window.jQuery || 
  document.write('<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/jq/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></' + 'script>')
</script>
```

The browser "parses" `<script>` tag contents by blindly searching for a closing `</script>` tag, paying no attention whatsoever to the syntax of the contents.

Comment: ah, good catch! I just tried the JS on the console and didn't see anything wrong :) +1

Comment: @Pointy so whenever I need to place a </script> tag within any script block all I have to do is split it into two concatenated strings to avoid getting them scanned by the browser...correct? Having said so this rule does not apply on the opening <script> tag?

Comment: @MChan yes that's right - the opening tag doesn't hurt anything because all the browser is looking for is the closing tag. Another way of doing it is to write it as `'<\/script>'` - the backslash-slash pair will end up as a plain slash in the string, but the browser won't think it's the closing tag.