# Adding a script-src in document.write in document.write

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have the following code:

```
<script>
document.writeln('<SCRIPT>window.JXG || document.write(\'\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="foo.js">\x3C/script>\')<\/SCRIPT>');
</script>
```

Which trows me a "unterminated string literal" SyntaxError, i can not imagine what i could possibly change that it will work. Someone has any clue how to solve this?

Comment: What's the point of that nested document.write/writeln?

Comment: It is part of a adserver, the outer document.writeln i can not controll and is added while the ad is uploaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: unterminated string literal javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790477/syntaxerror-unterminated-string-literal-javascript)